# What other fronts for mplayer are there beside smplayer and umplayer?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-player, mplayer

I am aware that it is hard to find better than SMPlayer - - not to mention that VLC is beyond compare ;-) 
But each has its own quirks -- and I like testing different alternatives even to the best applications out there, especially audio and video players. Without seeking there's no finding, is it?

Please report on players that you tested and like, not just links to names of players that exist but are hardly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is `gnome-mplayer`, `mplayer-gui`, `kmplayer` (kde) & a replacement for the totem browser plugin (totem-mozilla), `gecko-mediaplayer`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page which mentions many more than I was aware of:

MPlayer Frontends 
http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/projects.html#mplayer_frontends

My own recommendation is SMPlayer which is a really great front end for MPlayer that I have used for many years.

Hope this helps :).